# Cakephp form helper Model

Tags: cakephp, model, form-helpers

I am creating my form in the layout of my application and the view just have inputs.

```
// In layout
$this->Form->create('modelname');

// In view
$this->Form->input('fieldname');
```

Is there a way I can set default Model in my view just like inputDefaults

```
$this->Form->inputDefaults(array(
     'label' => false,
    'div' => false,
    'class' => 'fancy'
)
);
```

Cake Validation only works if it found input using [modelname][fieldname], so I can write in the view

```
 $this->Form->input('modelname.fieldname');
```

but I have to change all of my forms.

Is there any way I can set model name in the view??

Answer (score 0):

Why the .... are you creating your form in the layout?? This is very wrong unless there is some great reason for it (and I cannot see no such reason):

```
// In layout
$this->Form->create('modelname');
// In view
$this->Form->input('fieldname');
```

You should create separate forms in each view there is a form. Since each form is tied to a different model. Your validation is not working without `modelname.fieldname` since every form in every view does not attach itself to the right Model... 
You should creare every form in every view with:

```
$this->Form->create('specficmodelname');
```